# Definir bloco personalizado Sublime Text 3

Tags: css3, sublime-text

Gostaria de criar um bloco personalizado, quase como o comentário cria.

A pequena diferença é que ele será adaptado para minha necessidade, exemplo:
Tem um código CSS padrão, ele automaticamente quando crio a classe, ela cria o bloco padrão do sublime, como podemos ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: Extend line]

Vejamos a seta ao lado do nome da classe, ela cria por automático o bloco, como no exemplo da imagem abaixo com o bloco fechado:

[image: Extend Line 2]

Gostaria de criar esse bloco, só que personalizado para adicionar código a esse bloco e depois poder fecha-lo e abri-lo.

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi corretamente o que você quer, mas talvez o plugin [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace) com uma *mark override* possa ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

O uso de [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) do sublime text não resolve? Você pode criar snipptes de código e com o gatilho de alguma combinação de letras ele executa e monta o bloco para vc. Utilizo muito esse recurso programando em Ruby on Rails, onde posso criar alguns trechos de codigos(principalmente formulários) de maneira muito ágil.